# Custom List and Calendar View

Tags: list-view

I created a custom list to use with a calendar view. I set the calendar view as the default view.

I am trying to add the custom list as a web part and have the calendar view display. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it.Please see below directions for adding webpart and setting the view.

You can add the web part on your page by clicking the edit page. Just put the cursor on any region of the page and select insert from ribbon.

From the ribbon, select the webpart. In the category section select the apps and then your list name.

Once you do above process, web part configuration window will be luanched for the web part as show below. In the 'selected view' section, you can select the calendar view.

[image]